# SL MailChimp Subscribe Issue

Tags: mailchimp

I know the plugin is not being developed or supported by the author anymore, but does anyone have experience with SL MailChimp Subscribe?  It only seems to be half working for me.  Some members are being added and some are not, but in particular, it's not correctly adding the country members are selecting.  Only one country, Ireland is being updated in Mailchimp.

Can anyone shed some light one this?

Thanks,

Comment: Are all options created on MailChimp?

Comment: Hi Robson, thanks for your help. Everything seems to be ok in mailchimp, I've found a page in list settings which lists a number of countries, I've adding a few new countries to the list and tested the form.  Waiting to see if it works, fingers crossed.

Comment: In my tests, if the user chose an option that doesn't exist on MailChimp, the changes are refused.

Comment: Hi Robson, thanks for that information, I keep that in mind.  I don't think it's an issue with the details not being recorded in mailchimp.  I've looked into it and every entry seems to showing up ok now, so that's that problem solved.  The main problem is that we have a country field and only certain countries are being recorded.  If the user picks Ireland for example, that's recorded ok.  But if they pick the UK, the entry is recorded ok in Mailchimp, but the country is left blank.